# ReCharts - not able to see label when right aligned for stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I am creating an example of `StackBarChart` using `Recharts` library but I am not able to see the label when it's position is set to `"right"` though I am able to show the other label positions.

```
<BarChart width={400} height={300} data={data} layout="vertical">
   ...
   <Bar dataKey="pv" stackId="a" barSize={15} radius={[20,20,20,20]} fill="#8884d8" background={{fill: "#ddd", radius: [20,20,20,20]}} tick={false} />
   <Bar dataKey="uv" stackId="a" barSize={15} radius={[20,20,20,20]} fill="#aaa" >
     <LabelList dataKey="name" position="right" />
      {/* works fine <LabelList dataKey="name" position="top" /> */}
   </Bar>
</BarChart>
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sahilsolanki07/L3macevm/6/)(updated).

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your fiddle script [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L3macevm/2/).

You have to provide a correct `dataKey` field to `LabelList`, and put `LabelList` as a child of `Bar` component

UPDATED:

New [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3macevm/7/), you need `margin` in your case. So that the SVG reserved some spaces aside of the chart for additional text. NOTE that it is the `margin` **props** of the chart, not the `margin` from CSS style.

Comment: Seems old jsfiddle link was an unsaved draft, please have a look on the updated link.